# Ошибка Net::SMTP->auth() при наличии Authen::SASL::XS

Tags: perl, cygwin

Версии:

- Windows XP SP3 32-bit
- CYGWIN_NT-5.1 2.5.1(0.297/5/3) 2016-04-21 22:12 i686 Cygwin
- This is perl 5, version 22, subversion 2 (v5.22.2) built for cygwin-thread-multi-64int
- perl-Authen-SASL-2.16-2
- perl-Authen-SASL-XS-1.00-1

При установке пакета *perl-Authen-SASL-2.16-2* программа установки Cygwin
*setup-x86.exe* предупреждает, что он зависит от *perl-Authen-SASL-XS-1.00-1*.
В результате имеем такой фрагмент отладочного лога:

```
Net::SMTP::_SSL>>> Net::SMTP::_SSL
Net::SMTP::_SSL>>>   IO::Socket::SSL(2.027)
Net::SMTP::_SSL>>>     IO::Socket::IP(0.37)
Net::SMTP::_SSL>>>       IO::Socket(1.38)
Net::SMTP::_SSL>>>         IO::Handle(1.35)
Net::SMTP::_SSL>>>           Exporter(5.72)
Net::SMTP::_SSL>>>   Net::SMTP(3.05)
Net::SMTP::_SSL>>>     Net::Cmd(3.05)
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x206713a8)<<< 220 smtp3h.mail.yandex.net ESMTP...
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x206713a8)>>> EHLO localhost.localdomain
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x206713a8)<<< 250-smtp3h.mail.yandex.net
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x206713a8)<<< 250-8BITMIME
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x206713a8)<<< 250-PIPELINING
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x206713a8)<<< 250-SIZE 42991616
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x206713a8)<<< 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x206713a8)<<< 250-DSN
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x206713a8)<<< 250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
Connected to smtp.yandex.ru at /cygdrive/c/do/scripts/Yotools.pm line 559.
Auth'n as user-name... at /cygdrive/c/do/scripts/Yotools.pm line 562.
auth() error at /cygdrive/c/do/scripts/Yotools.pm line 564.
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x206713a8)>>> QUIT
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x206713a8)<<< 221 2.0.0 Closing connection.
```

И никакой диагностики от `Authen::SASL`. В процессе поиска причины был
заподозрен `Authen::SASL::XS`, который был деинсталирован. В результате всё
заработало:

```
...
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x206715f0)<<< 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x206715f0)<<< 250-DSN
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x206715f0)<<< 250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
Connected to smtp.yandex.ru at /cygdrive/c/do/scripts/Yotools.pm line 559.
Auth'n as user-name... at /cygdrive/c/do/scripts/Yotools.pm line 562.
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x206715f0)>>> AUTH LOGIN
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x206715f0)<<< 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x206715f0)>>> USER_NAME
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x206715f0)<<< 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x206715f0)>>> PASSWORD
Net::SMTP::_SSL=GLOB(0x206715f0)<<< 235 2.7.0 Authentication successful.
auth()'d at 'smtp.yandex.ru' as 'user-name'
...
```

В [POD-е](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Authen-SASL/lib/Authen/SASL.pod) `Authen::SASL` говорится:

> The framework allows different implementations of the connection class to be
>   plugged in...
>
> By default the order in which these plugins are selected is
>   `Authen::SASL::XS`, `Authen::SASL::Cyrus` and then `Authen::SASL::Perl`.
>
> If you want to change it or want to specifically use one implementation only
>   simply do
>
> ```
> use Authen::SASL qw(Perl);
> ```

Но мне не хочется лезть в код стандартного модуля `Net::SMTP`, который
использует для аутентификации плагин по умолчанию (`XS`).

Кроме того, на
[странице модуля](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Authen-SASL/lib/Authen/SASL.pod)
про зависимость от `Authen::SASL::XS` не говорится.

Google подсказал ещё пару мест ([раз](https://foswiki.org/Support/Faq69),
[два](https://rtcpan.develooper.com/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=100235)),
где упоминяются похожие проблемы, говорится, что `Authen::SASL::Perl` работает
достаточно хорошо, и рекомендуется удалить `Authen::SASL::XS`.

Достучаться до списка рассылки Cygwin мне не удалось, моё письмо с `@mail.ru`
ушло в никуда.

Так ли он нужен этот модуль?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Так ли он нужен этот модуль?

Если автовыбор отрабатывает без проблем, то и хорошо. Но можно и не удалять. Не знаю как под Windows и в 5.22, но в 5.18 под линуксом в подобных случаях часто работает указание альтернативной версии модуля до модуля, который от него зависит:

```
use Authen::SASL::Perl;
use Net::SMTP::SSL;
# и другие Authen::SASL::* уже не дёргаются
```

Comment: Перечитал описание `require` и `use` в _Книге в с Верблюдом_. Освежил в памяти, что `require` (который [вызывается] `use`) не загружает модуль повторно. Проверил в своих условиях, всё отработало как нужно. Вмешательства в `Net::SMTP` не потребовалось.

Comment: А Perl он и в винде/Cygwin -- Perl.

Comment: Забыл написать, я использовал: `use Authen::SASL qw(Perl);` перед
`use Net::SMTP;`

Comment: Ну, там могут быть различия в версиях модулей, как следствие  различия в реализациях выбора альтернатив. Но раз работает - значит,  всё OK :)